# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror, tomcat7

I'm currently working on a simple web project, for which I am using the SDK of [Polarion](http://www.polarion.com/). When trying to work with the according *.jar-Files, Tomcat 7 throws the following error message on start-up:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/polarion/alm/ws/client/session/SessionWebService;
```

According to the research I have undertaken, Java is trying to find an *instance* of com.polarion.ws.client.session.SessionWebService (thus the leading *L*). I have checked the classpath for the needed entry - it's there.

```
C:\Polarion\polarion\SDK\lib\com.polarion.alm.ws.client\wsclient.jar
```

As of now, I've run out of ideas what could have gone wrong. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot!
Simon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not supposed to put libraries for use in webapps in the CLASSPATH. You are supposed to put them in WEB-INF/lib in your webapp.

Comment: Typical beginner mistake. Copying the according .jar into WEB-INF/lib solved the problem immediately. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it still works like it did all those years ago when I last used Tomcat :)

Comment: @RobinGreen what if I want to put my jar file outside WEB-INF/lib ? Is it possible to set classpath from there ?

Comment: @Achyut Please ask a new question on Stackoverflow. I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Deployment and compilation are different processes. You should be aware of that, you can compile but if the necessary libraries are not accessible by the deployed application , you would get this exception.. As previous answer suggests, you should put necessary libraries WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application..

Comment: I'm glad I understand the difference now.